# How to build Jmeter 5.4.3 in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

When ever I am trying to build my JMETET 5.4.3 Source code in intellij If am getting the following errors which I am not able to resolve the errors are

```html
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':src:dist:verifyReleaseDependencies'.
> External dependencies differ (you could update src\dist\src\dist\expected_release_jars.csv if you add -PupdateExpectedJars):
    55965681 => 55965659 bytes (-22 bytes)
  
  -  207909 log4j-1.2-api-2.17.0.jar
  -  301892 log4j-api-2.17.0.jar
  - 1789565 log4j-core-2.17.0.jar
  -   24258 log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.0.jar

==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':src:protocol:http:test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///E:/JMeter/apache-jmeter-5.4.3_src/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/src/protocol/http/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
```

Can anyone help me with this.

And is there a way in Intellij to to change your gradle version to a older version please let me know.

is there a way to build jmeter 5.4.3 in ANT rather than Gradle?

Comment: Does it work with Gradle from the command line outside of IntelliJ?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_version_install on how to change Gradle version in your project.

Comment: I tried using the cmd but in that case I am unable to use the 'gradle build' command as it was not avaliable in the task list it only contains init and wrapper tasks @EgorKlepikov

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue:

[image: IntelliJ build of JMeter 5.4.3]

And I strongly doubt anyone can as it would have been noticed long time ago, [JMeter 5.4.3 was released in December 2021](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41) and presumably a lot of [contributors](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Contributors/) were adding their code and building/testing JMeter since then.

Personally I'm not a JMeter contributor but I need to compile it from time to time in order to amend it to my projects needs.

Just in case the steps I normally follow:

1. Get the required JMeter source version from Apache archives, in your case it would be https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/source/apache-jmeter-5.4.3_src.zip
2. Verify the [checksum](https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/source/apache-jmeter-5.4.3_src.tgz.sha512) of the downloaded archive just in case
3. Unpack the archive
4. In IntelliJ Idea open [`build.gradle.kts`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.3/build.gradle.kts) as a Project
5. Wait for half an hour
6. ....
7. Profit?

Also be aware that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article and [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so maybe attempt to compile [JMeter 5.5](https://lists.apache.org/thread/k575c2oqnr0pv52fckcg399o4nkqt8c6) will be more successful?

Comment: When I am trying to build it initially I am getting 

Execution failed for task ':src:protocol:http:test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///E:/New%20folder/apache-jmeter-5.4.3/src/protocol/http/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

this error and when I am opening the file Location I am directed to a page where it shows 

Failed tests
Tests
[1] HttpClient4
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: HTTP is using a custom DNS resolver, so it must fail resolving localhost 
url: http://localhost:9113/index.html
response: Not Found

Comment: data.size: 84
data: No response could be served as there are no stub mappings in this WireMock instance.
 ==> expected: <Non HTTP response message: Failed to resolve host name: localhost> but was: <Not Found>

Comment: Have you faced anything like this?

Comment: I don't think this is an appropriate place for troubleshooting your Windows netwokring configuration. Try adding `127.0.0.1 localhost` line to `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file